# Extract text from ajaxed body using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom, html-parsing

I am trying to extract text from body downloaded via ajax.

I can not inject this new body into iframe or into one of my elements because scripts within could break my page.

What I hoped will fork for me is:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
  dataType: "text", /* this will avoid evaluating scripts */
  url: href,
  success: function (data) {
    var body = data.split('<body').pop().split('</body>')[0];
    if (body) {
      body = '<body' + body + '</body>';
      var pageText = $(body).find("style").remove().end()
          .find("script").remove().end()
          .find("noscript").remove().end()
          .text().replace(/\s{2,}/gi, " ").toLowerCase();
      if (pageText.length > 0)
          console.log(pageText);
});
```

I have tried placing downloaded body into DIV element because jQuery ignores BODY, replacing find.remove with detach but with not much of success.

Is there any standard solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not ignore body, see [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/editedredx/7CV6m/).

does this not work?

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
  dataType: "text", /* this will avoid evaluating scripts */
  url: href,
  success: function (data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    var newHTML = $("body", $data).html();
    $("body").html(newHTML);  
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(data)` will create disconnected fragment but IE will execute contained scripts. So you need to get rid of them before creating fragment. This is something jQuery.load already does (http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L70).

Comment: Load is only useful when you are inserting html into an element but I have to have it in variable for further processing. I had to avoid executing scripts as well.
I needed a text from body and not HTML as you can see from my initial question.
This works for me nicely now.

`var pageText = $(data).not('script').not('style').text();`

I had to enforce script removal because in some cases `$(data).text()` did not remove scripts or styles.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does it all for you (removes scripts and optionally captures only the desired fragment).

E.g.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Loads contents of element with id `container` from url `ajax/test.html` into an element (on current page) with id `result`.

Comment: Hi Marko,All I am trying to do is to capture text ONLY and not the entire element. By calling load it will try to download images as well. Another problem is with BODY used as selector nothing is loaded.

Comment: If I understand correctly: You could load it in disconnected `div` node (create it with `$('<div>')`) so it doesn't trigger resource loading, then your entire `.html()` (of that node) is the markup of the body of your response (or `.text()` is the textual content of your response). You don't need special selector to select everything.

Comment: Even with detached div - load() is still attempting to download and load scripts from <head>. Another problem is text() method is ignoring <blockquote> and most likely some other. I need to capture this text. for example after calling text()  on "http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm" I will loose all important text.